# Show other view wile loading in Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am creating a UIViewController which have an animation on it and I want it to be displayed while "loading" or changing views. Is there a way so I can show that view in top of the others while they're doing their business logic and when they're done call in their respectives ViewDidLoad functions, a call to "hide" this facade view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display loading overlay which has your own custom animation and you want to show/hide this loading overlay on top of any `View` or `ViewController`. If my understanding is correct then you can achieve this as follows:

Suppose `loadingOverlay` is your animation view instance. 
Assign some unique `Tag` to this:

```
loadingOverlay.Tag = 1678;
```

This can be any number which uniquely identifies your loading overlay view from all other views from `UIWindow` in any ViewController.

**Show:**

```
UIWindow myKeyWindow = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
myKeyWindow.AddSubView(loadingOverlay);
```

**Hide:**

```
var loadingOverlay = myKeyWindow.ViewWithTag(1678);
//Remove completely
loadingOverlay?.RemoveFromSuperView();
//OR
//Simply hide it
loadingOverlay?.Hidden = true;
```

**Note**: If you want to use `Hidden` property, then you have to make sure that you add this view into `UIWindow` only once.

> So, ideally, anything which you want to display on top of anything,
>   should go into `KeyWindow (UiWindow)`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I created a function called show, inside the LoadingOverlay.cs file.

The problem is that the view won't appear when I call this function. should I create it inside the class that is performing the operation?